# Python: How to print one more line after my result from file?

Tags: python, printing

In my input file I have many lines, I am searching only one, which meets my requirements. And that's already done. But I need to print a line after this line which has been already found.
Example of input:

```
line 1 x
line 2 a
line 3 a
line 3 a
```

I am searching for line where is `x` inside.

```
for lines in input:
  if 'x' in lines:
    print (lines)
```

Result: `line 1 x`
So now I need to show one line after my result

Expected result:

```
line 1 x
line 2 a
```

I also tried:

```
for lines in input:
  if 'x' in lines:
    print (lines, '\n', lines[lines.index(lines) + 0:100])
```

Comment: simply update to  if 'x' in line:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try splitting your input into a list first:

```
a = input.split('\n')

for lines in a:
    if 'x' in lines:
        print (lines, '\n', a[a.index(lines) + 1])
```

Comment: thank for fast answer, please take a look on my edit in main post

Comment: yes, thank You. i have used a=a.splitlines() at start, but is seems to be the same thing, cheers!